# my code works fine for one row in the binary tree, the second row overrides the first

Tags: c, tree

I'm trying to build my binary search tree. If I input 2 rows it works fine but if I input more rows it overrides the second row but it does allocate me memory for the next row(third for example).

Can anyone help me fix this issue? I don't understand where I'm wrong here. Logically should work fine.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct node
{
    int number;
    node* left;                             
    node* right;
}node ;

void print_tree(node* root);                    //
void free_tree(node* root);                     //
bool search_tree(node* root, int number);       //   function declerations
struct node* insert_tree(node* root, int number);
struct node* new_node(int number);



int main(void)
{
    int number = 0;
    int size = 0;
    printf("please enter how many numbers you want to add to the tree : \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &size);
    printf("the amount of numbers you want to add is : %i \n", size);
    node* n = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n == NULL)          //malloc check
    {
        free(n);
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("please enter the numbers you want to add to the tree : \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &number);
    n->left = NULL; 
    n->right = NULL; 
    n->number = number;
    for (int i = 1; i < size  ; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &number);
        insert_tree(n, number);
    }
    printf("the inorder numbers of your tree are :\n");
    print_tree(n);
    free_tree(n);
}


struct node* insert_tree(node* root, int number)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = new_node(number);        //create new node
        return root;
    }
    else if (number < root->number)         //go left if number is less than root
    {
        root->left = insert_tree(root->left, number);
    }
     else if (number > root->number)            //go right if number is bigger than root
    {
        root->right = insert_tree(root->right, number);                 
    }
    else                                 //if equal 
        return root;
}

struct node* new_node(int number)
{
    node* n = NULL;
    n = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));        //allocate memory for new node
    if (n == NULL)                              //malloc check
    {   
        free(n);
        exit(1);
    }
    n->left = NULL;
    n->right = NULL;
    n->number = number;
    return n;
}


void print_tree(node* root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        print_tree(root->left);     //print left side
        printf("%i\n", root->number);   //print number
        print_tree(root->right);    //pring right side
    }
    return;
}

void free_tree(node* root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        free_tree(root->left);  //move throught left
        free_tree(root->right); //move through right
        free(root);             //free root
    }


}

bool search_tree(node * root, int number)
{
    if (root == NULL)       // tree is empty
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (number < root->number) //move left untill we find the number
    {
        search_tree(root->left, number);
    }
    else if (number > root->number) //move right untill we find the number
    {
        search_tree(root->right, number);   
    }
    else                        //number is root number
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Read the warnings or turn up warnings if you are not seeing anything. It should tell you that `insert_tree` is not returning a value in all code paths. That probably isn't *the* problem as you are not using the return value anyway (but you really should be for a more correct implementation).

Comment: this code does not compile (gcc version 9.4.0)

Comment: it does compile for me without warnings in VS-2022

Comment: That is not good, in C every warning is a potential problem. In your case you should have listened to the warnings, they caused the problem. In C not returning anything means, using what is already in the return register. This could be the last thing a function returned or something random.

Answer (score 1):

You code has some errors while compiling, but after fixing them it works without trouble:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


typedef struct node {
    int number;
    struct node* left;                             
    struct node* right;
}node ;

void print_tree(node* root);                    //
void free_tree(node* root);                     // this comment is useless:
bool search_tree(node* root, int number);       // function declerations
struct node* insert_tree(node* root, int number);
struct node* new_node(int number);



int main(void)
{
    int number = 0;
    int size = 0;
    printf("please enter how many numbers you want to add to the tree : \n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("the amount of numbers you want to add is : %i \n", size);
    node* n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n == NULL)          //malloc check <- this too
    {
        free(n);
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("please enter the numbers you want to add to the tree : \n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    n->left = NULL; 
    n->right = NULL; 
    n->number = number;
    for (int i = 1; i < size  ; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &number);
        insert_tree(n, number);
    }
    printf("the inorder numbers of your tree are :\n");
    print_tree(n);
    free_tree(n);
}


struct node* insert_tree(node* root, int number)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = new_node(number);
    }
    else if (number < root->number)
    {
        root->left = insert_tree(root->left, number);
    }
    else if (number > root->number)
    {
        root->right = insert_tree(root->right, number);
    }
    return root;
}

struct node* new_node(int number)
{
    node* n = NULL;
    n = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n == NULL)
    {   
        free(n);
        exit(1);
    }
    n->left = NULL;
    n->right = NULL;
    n->number = number;
    return n;
}


void print_tree(node* root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        print_tree(root->left);     //print left side
        printf("%i\n", root->number);   //print number
        print_tree(root->right);    //pring right side
    }
    return;
}

void free_tree(node* root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        free_tree(root->left);  //move throught left
        free_tree(root->right); //move through right
        free(root);             //free root
    }


}

bool search_tree(node * root, int number)
{
    if (root == NULL)       // tree is empty
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (number < root->number) //move left untill we find the number
    {
        return search_tree(root->left, number);
    }
    else if (number > root->number) //move right untill we find the number
    {
        return search_tree(root->right, number);   
    }
    else                        //number is root number
        return true;
}
```

I think the problem was, that your `insert_tree()` function didn't return root sometimes, so the old root was still in some register.

Do not comment the obvious, like "function declerations or malloc check".
Also you do not have to cast malloc output like this: "(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));". `void*` can be implicitly casted to anything: "malloc(sizeof(node));".

Comment: also if i malloc without the (node*) before it gives me errors on the line maybe im missing something?

Comment: You are welcome. And remember, warnings are great and help you find errors.

Comment: The problem is i didnt get a warning on my original code maybe my debugger is misconfigured

Comment: Did you compile with "-Wall -Wextra"?